# inquirer.js - combine BottomBar with sequential log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a Node CLI command using `inquirer.js` which can take quite a while to complete, so I'm trying to update the UI something like this:

```
✓ Thing A complete
✓ Thing B complete
✓ Thing C complete
⠹ Loading...

{display json result}
```

(Where 'Loading...' stays at the bottom and logs appear as they complete).

Simplified, the command has a structure like this:

```
ui.startLoader()
thingA()
  .then((res) => {
    ui.log('✓ Thing A complete')
    return res
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.reduce(thingB, Promise.resolve())
  })
  .then((res) => {
    ui.log('✓ Thing B complete')
    return res
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.reduce(thingC, Promise.resolve())
  })
  .then((res) => {
    ui.log('✓ Thing C complete')
    return res
  })
  .then(ui.json)
  .catch(console.log)
  .then(ui.exit)
```

`ui.startloader` simply sets up the BottomBar as described in the official [example](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/master/examples/bottom-bar.js) and appears to be working fine.

When `ui.log` is `console.log('\n' . text)`, my output is:

```
⠋ Loading...
✓ Thing A complete
⠹ Loading...
✓ Thing B complete
⠴ Loading...
✓ Thing C complete

{display json result}
```

When `ui.log` is inquirer.js' `BottomBar.log.write(text)`, my output is just:

```
✓ Thing A complete
⠹ Loading...

{display json result}
```

The 'Loading...' line stays at the bottom, but only the first log displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue in Inquirer.js. I came across it when up updating from 0.12.0 to the newer ES6 Promise based interface.

I've opened an issue:
https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/485

And put in a pull request for a fix:
https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/pull/486

Hopefully it is accepted.

Comment: Thanks! Your fix works for me, I'll wait to see what happens with the PR then mark correct :)

Comment: Looks like this has already been merged and released in [v3.0.0](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/releases/tag/v3.0.0)